# Group by unique ids to calculate number of days in R

Tags: r, date, group-by

i want to find how many days a unique id has worked in this df by abstracting the max date minus min date.

```
structure(list(id = c("f1", "f2", "f2", "f4", "f5", "f2", "f3", 
"f1", "f1", "f3", "f4", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2"), 
 date = structure(c(18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 
18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 18687, 
18687), class = "Date")), row.names = c(2L, 4L, 8L, 15L, 17L, 
18L, 21L, 25L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 40L, 42L, 48L, 52L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried this but I get weird numbers

```
df_total_days_per_id<-df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(xx1 = max(date)-min(date)) %>% #by user find range
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(number_of_days = sum(xx1))
```

Comment: All dates in your data are the same (2021-03-01). Are you sure your dataframe is correct?

Comment: @Bas yes this is just a sample (the first rows of the df) normally for every id there are a lot of same inputs regarding dates because they have worked the same day a lot of times with interruptions. The initial df had also the time they worked but i split date and time. Now i just want to fix this code to calculate how many days every id worked

Comment: Do you instead want maybe `max(date) - min(date) + 1`? If `max(date)` and `min(date)` are equal, I assume you want to count it as 1 day worked.

Comment: @Bas but there are not equal in every observation. For example, the same id will 6 inputs of 2021-03-01 because he worked 6 times in that day, he will have 7 inputs of 2021-03-02 because he worked 7 times in that day and 5 inputs of 2021-03-03 and so on. What I am trying to is to abstract max date minus min date so the final result will 2 in the example I just mentioned, that means , that he worked 2 days

Comment: You should probably give us more useful sample data than one with all the dates the same. That way we can all be on the same page about what should happen when the dates are not the same--and we can use the sample data to test the results in that case too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code I can make an estimate of why you are getting "weird numbers".

The function `mutate()` *adds* a new column to the existing table. Let's forget about groups for a moment and assume the following dates:

```
2022-01-01 
2022-01-11 
2022-01-21
```

You want the answer to be 20, right? 21 minus 1. However with your `mutate()` function you create this:

```
2022-01-01   20 days
2022-01-11   20 days
2022-01-21   20 days
```

and then in the last operation you sum all these 20s to reach 60 days. Obviously this is wrong.

Instead of using `mutate()` we use `summarize()` like so:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(number_of_days = max(date)-min(date)+1) #added +1 for correction
```

after this there is no need to add another `group_by()` or `sum()`

**Edit:**

I noticed that you are talking about the number of days worked. So if we take the example above you might instead want to output 3 instead of 20 because there are days inbetween that were skipped. If this is the case you should use a different function in your `summarize()` altogether.

For this we can use the function `n_distinct()` which counts the amount of unique values in a group, like so:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(number_of_days = n_distinct(date))
```

Comment: basically, every unique day is a day that he worked. so in your example, the correct answer is 3 and not 20 . (sorry my mistake I didn't clarify this)

Comment: Yea, I realized that after your last comment. I already edited my answer and added a solution for that specific issue

Comment: Thanks for the `n_distinct()` I had 
    `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(number_of_days = length(unique(date)) )`